# Integrating full calendar ionic view

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I have updated all the cordova package just am an beginner of ionic. Anyone can help to integrate full calendar view in ionic page.
controller page

```
.controller('pageCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaCalendar) {

    $scope.createEvent = function() {
        $cordovaCalendar.createEvent({
            title: 'Space Race',
            location: 'The Moon',
            notes: 'Bring sandwiches',
            startDate: new Date(2015, 0, 15, 18, 30, 0, 0, 0),
            endDate: new Date(2015, 1, 17, 12, 0, 0, 0, 0)
        }).then(function (result) {
                console.log("Event created successfully");
            }, function (err) {
                console.error("There was an error: " + err);
            });
    }

})
```

view page

```
<ion-view title="Page">

    <ion-content overflow-scroll="true" padding="true" class="has-header"></ion-content>

    <ion-content ng-controller="pageCtrl">
        <ion-view class="calendar" ng-click="createEvent()">Create Event</ion-view>
    </ion-content>

</ion-view>
```

Comment: You need to provide more detail.  What is going wrong? What do you want to happen?

Comment: while I trying this code create event button doesn't perform any action. But actually I need to display full calendar on that page.

Comment: What you are describing is two issues. One, your create event isn't working, and second, you want to display a calendar on the page. You need to edit the question to be more specific and focus on one at a time. I've got a full blog entry on this topic as an FYI: http://www.raymondcamden.com/2015/09/18/integrating-the-calendar-into-your-ionic-app